# InvalidArgumentException: The service definition "my.markdown.parser" does not exist

Tags: php, symfony, bundle

i try to instal bundle:KnpLabs/KnpMarkdownBundle but i have this error :

```
InvalidArgumentException: The service definition "my.markdown.parser" does not exist.
```

this is a section of requires :

```
"php": ">=5.3.3",
        "symfony/symfony": "~2.4",
        "doctrine/orm": "~2.2,>=2.2.3",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "1.3.*@dev",
        "twig/extensions": "~1.0",
        "symfony/assetic-bundle": "~2.3",
        "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "~2.3",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "~2.4",
        "sensio/distribution-bundle": "~2.3",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "~3.0",
        "sensio/generator-bundle": "~2.3",
        "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "~2.0",
        "jms/di-extra-bundle": "dev-master",
        "doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle": "2.2.*@dev",
        "doctrine/data-fixtures": "1.0.*@dev",
        "stof/doctrine-extensions-bundle": "~1.1@dev",
        "knplabs/knp-markdown-bundle": "~1.3"
```

and section of appkernel :

```
$bundles = array(
            //....
            new JMS\DiExtraBundle\JMSDiExtraBundle($this),
            new JMS\AopBundle\JMSAopBundle(),
            new Knp\Bundle\MarkdownBundle\KnpMarkdownBundle(),
            new Stof\DoctrineExtensionsBundle\StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle(),
        );
```

this is the part where I used a bundle :

```
<i>Le {{ article.date|date('d/m/Y') }}, par {{ article.auteur|markdown }}.</i>
{# On affiche les Competence éventuelles #}
{% if article.articleCompetences.count > 0 %}
    <i>
      Competences :
      {% for categorie in article.articleCompetences %}
        {{ categorie.competence.nom }}{% if not loop.last %}, {% endif %}
      {% endfor %}
    </i>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Are you trying to change the parser implementation to `my.markdown.parser`? Does the service exist?

Comment: I do not know, I followed the installation that exists in github :https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpMarkdownBundle

Comment: Show us the code where you're trying to use it

Comment: This is how to use it as from the docs: `$html = $this->container->get('markdown.parser')->transformMarkdown($text);`. Perhaps you might have prefixed the service name by accident?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you are intending to configure the bundle to use your own parser implementation, you *shouldn't* have to add this to your bundle.

```
knp_markdown:
    parser:
        service: my.markdown.parser
```

Just remove it, and I think by default it will use the `Knp\Bundle\MarkdownBundle\Parser\MarkdownParser` parser.

Comment: I remove it in file config.yml but i have this error:
FatalErrorException: Compile Error: Can't inherit abstract function Knp\Bundle\MarkdownBundle\MarkdownParserInterface::transform() (previously declared abstract in Michelf\MarkdownInterface) in C:\wamp\www\Symfony1\vendor\knplabs\knp-markdown-bundle\Knp\Bundle\MarkdownBundle\Parser\MarkdownParser.php line 16

Comment: Looking at the [source](https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpMarkdownBundle/blob/master/MarkdownParserInterface.php) of `MarkdownParserInterface` and [that](https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpMarkdownBundle/blob/master/Parser/MarkdownParser.php) of `MarkdownParser`, there shouldn't be a `transform()` method anymore; it's now called `transformMarkdown($text);`